# Apply Group By Cause on as variable Name

Tags: sql, group-by

```
select CASE (id_referral) 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
  WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
  WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
  ELSE 'Other'
  END as referralName ,
  count(id_referral) gCount 
from referralDetails
group by referralName
```

I am getting error

> Invalid column name 'referralName'

Comment: i am getting error Invalid column name 'referralName'.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please tried with below query

```
SELECT referralName, count(id_referral) gCount
FROM (SELECT CASE (id_referral) 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
  WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
  WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
  ELSE 'Other'
  END as referralName ,
  id_referral
from referralDetails) tbl
group by referralName
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference a column alias in a `GROUP BY` so you have two options.

You can reuse the `CASE` in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select CASE (id_referral) 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
  WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
  WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
  ELSE 'Other'
  END as referralName ,
  count(id_referral) gCount 
from referralDetails
group by CASE (id_referral) 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
  WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
  WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
  ELSE 'Other'
  END
```

Or you can wrap your query in a subquery:

```
select referralName, count(id_referral) gCount 
from
(
  select CASE (id_referral) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    ELSE 'Other'
    END as referralName ,
    id_referral
  from referralDetails
 ) d
 group by referralName
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try your query in a subquery:

```
select referralName, count(id_referral) gCount From
(SELECT 
CASE (id_referral )
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    ELSE 'Other'
    END 
 referralName ,
    id_referral
  from referralDetails ) AS TABLE1 GROUP BY Test
```

or You can TRY this one which is return column group count with extra column

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
CASE (id_referral )
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    ELSE 'Other'
    END 
 referralName,

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  (CASE (id_referral )
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    ELSE 'Other'
    END )  ORDER BY id_referral ) AS NO,

 COUNT(id_referral) OVER(PARTITION BY  (CASE (id_referral )
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    ELSE 'Other'
    END )) AS gCount,

* FROM referralDetails)  AS TABLE1 WHERE no =1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY referralName ORDER BY id_referral) AS NO,
COUNT(id_referral) OVER(PARTITION BY referralName) AS gCount,
* FROM
(SELECT CASE (id_referral % 100 )
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Treatment' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Medication' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Diagnosis / Tests' 
    ELSE 'Other'
    END AS referralName ,* FROM dbo.referralDetails) AS T1)AS T2 WHERE No = 1
```